# use force:navigateToSObject in lightning experience to move to relatedList tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigation

I am working on `force:navigateToSObject` for redirecting to Sobject related list page

```
        var sobjId = component.get('v.sobjId');
        console.log('====sobjId=====',sobjId);
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
          "recordId": sobjId,
          "slideDevName": "related" //related , detail, chatter
        });
        navEvt.fire();
```

But I am not able to redirect to related list. It always lands on the details page

If you read the documents, it says like [Doc Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm)

> slideDevName -  This attribute has no effect in Lightning Experience.

if this is the case how to redirect to other tabs in Lightning record detail page?

Comment: Yes, slideDevName has no effect in Lightning Experience.. Which needs to be fixed by salesforce. We need this asap. @sfdcfox any work around for it ?